# Scanner line not available error

Tags: java

I call the `Scanner.nextLine()` method from two different scanner objects at two different methods. Sometimes when I call the `Scanner.nextLine()` from the second method, it gives me an "*line not available*" error. What might be the problem?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe {

    private final String COMPUTER = "computer";
    private final String PLAYER = "player";

    /**
     * Asks the user to choose a letter ('X' or 'O')
     * and checks if the input is valid.
     */
    public void askLetter() {
        System.out.println("Please enter 'X' or 'O': ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String letter = input.nextLine().toUpperCase().trim();
        while (!letter.equals("X") && !letter.equals("O")) {
            System.out.println("Please enter 'X' or 'O': ");
            letter = input.nextLine().toUpperCase().trim();
        }
        input.close();
    }


    /**
     * Asks the user to choose who goes first. 
     * @return 'computer' or 'player'
     */
    public String decide() {
        //System.out.println("Choose who goes first('player' or 'computer'): ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String first = input.nextLine().toUpperCase().trim();
        while (!first.equals(COMPUTER) && !first.equals(PLAYER)) {
            System.out.println("Choose who goes first('player' or 'computer'): ");
            first = input.nextLine().toUpperCase().trim();
        }
        input.close();
        return first;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TicTacToe tictac = new TicTacToe();
        tictac.askLetter();
        tictac.decide();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you switch the order does it still occur in the one that comes second or does it still happen in the same method?

Comment: my first question is why the two scanner objects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `askLetter` method closes the scanner... which will close `System.in`. You're then trying to reuse `System.in` within `decide`.

Change the constructor to accept a `Scanner`, which you create in `main`. Then retain that scanner in a field and use it in both methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    TicTacToe tictac = new TicTacToe(scanner);
    tictac.askLetter();
    tictac.decide();
    // You might want to close the scanner here, but you don't really have to.
}
```

This *also* helps make your code more testable - you could now use a `Scanner` which is backed by fake data (e.g. a `StringReader`).